# Есть ли js библиотека для подобных переходов при скролле?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, прокрутка, transition

Мне нравится переход при скроле между блоками на этом сайте https://www.squarespace.com/about/timeline , но не знаю есть ли уже какое-то готовое решения для подобного скролла в виде библиотеки или еще чего-то. Я нашел пока что только pagePiling.js и FullPage.js

Comment: Отвратительнейший сайт

Comment: Почему вы так считаете?